# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo mi **prueba.html** , y dentro llamo a **index.js** que está dentro de ***routes*** , pero no me lo pilla y la página se muestra en blanco.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="es">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Prueba</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/routes/index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  
// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

// The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
var root = {
  hello: () => {
    return 'Hello world!';
  },
};

// Run the GraphQL query '{ hello }' and print out the response
graphql(schema, '{ hello }', root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  res.send(response);
  
 
});

  
});

module.exports = router;
```

Dejo también la estructura del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No te entiendo .

Comment: app.use('/prueba', express.static('public'));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

Comment: Lo he usado como dices , pero me sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Esta ruta: `src="/routes/index.js"` que pretendes enlazar en tu `html` no es válida. Por otro lado, el código de tu archivo `index.js` es para `NodeJS` y no se ejecutará en un contexto de cliente (como el navegador). Lo que no entiendo es ¿porqué quieres ejecutar código de servidor directamente en el cliente?

Comment: ¿No te funciona con `src="routes/index.js"`?

Comment: No , no me funciona así